Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA to return years covered by start and end dates?
I have a table with start and end dates. I want an ARRAYFORMULA that will spit out a comma separated list of years within the start and end dates for each row.
For example:



start
end




2021-02-01
2024-03-13


2019-01-01
2019-03-01


2020-01-31
2022-02-01



The expected result with ARRAYFORMULA in C1:



start
end
years




2021-02-01
2024-03-13
2021, 2022, 2023, 2024


2019-01-01
2019-03-01
2019


2020-01-31
2022-02-01
2020, 2021, 2022





You may try:
=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(or(a="",b=""),,join(", ",unique(index(year(sequence(b-a+1,1,a))))))))



Thank you so much. I keep forgetting I can use MAP instead of ARRAYFORMULA.

You can also try this non-lambda solution:
=ArrayFormula(LET(startDate,$A$2:$A$4,
                  endDate,$B$2:$B$4,
                  startYear,YEAR(startDate),
                  endYear,YEAR(endDate),
                  minStartYear,MIN(startyear),
                  maxEndYear,MAX(endYear),
                  numYear,maxEndYear-minStartYear+1,
                  yearList,SEQUENCE(numYear,1,minStartYear),
                  yearListText,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,yearList),
                  finalYearList,IF((startDate<>"")*(endDate<>""),REGEXEXTRACT(yearListText,"("&startYear&".*"&endYear&"|"&startYear&")"),),
                  finalYearList))


The formula consists of 6 parts. Let's break this down!
First, we get the start year and end year using the YEAR Function:

Next, we'll get the min start year and the max end year from the previous results:

Next, we'll calculate the number of years between the min start year and max end year:

4th, Once we have the number of years, we can now create a list of years using the SEQUENCE Function:

5th, we'll concatenate the year list into a text year list:

Finally, we'll use the REGEXEXTRACT Function and extract the range of years from the text year list. We'll use the startYear and endYear as part of our regex:

